Resolving Driver Issues in Ubuntu 20.04 with Real-Time Kernel
I have Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 5.15.0-113, and I installed the real-time kernel version 5.9.1 because I couldn't find the real-time version for my current kernel. The installation went well, and I can now boot using the real-time kernel. However, the issue I'm facing is that none of the drivers (LAN, Graphics, etc.) work with the real-time kernel. How can I install the drivers for the real-time kernel?

How did you install the rea-time kernel? When you install a kernel, you also need to install the corresponding /lib/modules/<kernel_version> directory tree. A kernel and modules are built together and must be installed together. This should happen automatically if you are installing from packages, but if you're doing things manually you'll need to take care of it yourself.
